# Can I specify not for IOS 5 in iTunes for my app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

My app is broken by iOS 5 and I want to prevent people purchasing it until I develop a fix. The IOS Deployment Target in Xcode is iOS 4.2, but iTunes says "Requires iOS 4.2 or later". How do I get rid of the "or later"?

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain you can't. I would recommend just stating in your app's description that it currently does not work on iOS 5 and that a fix is coming.

Comment: To be on the safe side, I pulled the app from iTunes while I work on the fix.